# Select 1 from dual where exists (select ....). Returns 1 even if the table is completely empty?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm using a Select 1 from dual statement to see if new data that comes into my system is actually new or not, if it is new then it's gonna be inserted, if it is not then it's gonna be updated in the database.

```
sql.CommandText = "select 1 from dual where exists (select * from my table where hour = " + hour + " and zone = '" + zone+ "' and date = TO_DATE('" + mydate + "','DD-MM-YY'))"
```

The problem however is that after running the statement, it returns the 1 value even if the conditions for it aren't met, even if the table is completely empty. How could this happen?
I'm using VB, .NET framework 3.5 and Oracle 10g.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6eb12/7 Is there maybe something you haven't mentioned? If you want to do update/insert, why not simply use a `MERGE` statement?

Comment: I decided not on the MERGE statement because the examples I saw were more about actually merging 2 tables into 1, the data I'm updating/inserting comes from an XML file, so not from an actual database.

Comment: You can easily use a MERGE statement with "constant" values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed4de/6

Comment: Are you sure it returns a result with one row and the value `1` and not a result where the column is named `1` and 0 rows?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
  FROM mytable m
 WHERE m.hour = hour 
   AND m.zone = zone
   AND m.date = TO_DATE( mydate,'DD-MM-YY'))
   AND ROWNUM = 1
```

The result will be either 0 or 1. Since you only care about the existence of the row, the `ROWNUM = 1` will cause the query to quit as soon as it finds a matching entry and will prevent you from scanning the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sign(count(1))` to get the count.

```
select sign(count(1)) cnt 
from my_table 
where hour = " + hour + " and zone = '" + zone+ "' 
    and date = TO_DATE('" + mydate + "','DD-MM-YY'))"
```